# NetLogo Fleet Battle

Tags: netlogo

I'm in college, very new to coding, and I'm in the middle of an assignment with NetLogo to create a complex system of some kind. I've decided to create a fleet battle with ships that can sense each other as well as enemy fire, and will group up and try to avoid enemy fire while firing back at them. In addition, I would like each team (friendly and enemy) to have 3 'flagships' that become primary targets when spotted. If all three are destroyed on one side, that team loses.

These are the things I cannot figure out how to program:

1. Spawn both teams randomly spaced within a set area
2. Get 'missiles' to fire from each turtle with a set delay
3. Get turtles to sense enemy ships and enemy missiles, and fire at the enemy ships and avoid the missiles.
4. How to get a ship to detect being hit by a missile so that its energy (HP) goes down.
5. How to get ships to sense one another and group together, especially around 'flagships'
6. This one is a long shot but it would be nice - how to get ships to 'aim' at other ships.

Any and all help is appreciated! If you can help with any of these, please let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good start of a description of your model and enough for someone to make an implementation. Probably the best use of StackOverflow would be to take a first effort at making your model, sharing what you've done and asking specific questions where you're stuck. As a nudge to get you going on targeting, I would look into Netlogo primitives like `face`, `in-cone` and `in-radius`